# Understanding request.data in django view

Tags: python, django, view, request, response

I tried looking at different resources on the internet regarding this request and **request.data** in django, but I couldn't fully understand it.

Why this request parameter is kept inside the function? What are we passing in this request parameter?? Also, what does this request. data do??

def index(request):

```
content = {

'Blogdata': Blog.objects.all(),

}

return render(request, 'index.html', content)



def somefunction (request):
    
    data=request.data
```

As you can see I have two functions above both of them have request paramter inside the function. Also, I need the explanation on this request.data as this has to be used multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should understand about HTTP Request(Header, Body). When you type in form and send to server, browser get data with name and add values into body request. In the backend server, we will get data from body with name.
Example:
I have form fill your name:

```
<form action="/signin" method="get" name="myForm">
  <label for="name">Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Send form data!">
</form>
```

You type name : "Khoa", browser get values "Khoa" from input and add key:values with name in . Like this: "name": "Khoa"

In server django, you can get data with using request.data.get("name") = "Khoa"
request.data is body HTTP send to servere, "name" is key part of body have values is "Khoa"

Comment: So if the data are being sent, for eg in a post method, it will come in a request object?? also if data are not being sent, for eg in GET request, GET is passed in a request?? is that it??

Comment: In GET, Server get data in respone with request user